# Connect IQ session.save() "failed"

Tags: garmin

I have this function for saving session on my app. FIT file is created but after one second I am receiving notification "failed". This is I think because it is not sync with Garmin connect. I am calling `popView(WatchUi.SLIDE_IMMEDIATE);` after `stopAndSaveActivityRecording()`.

Can I somehow disable this message? My code is:

```
function stopAndSaveActivityRecording() {
   if (Toybox has :ActivityRecording) {                         
        if ((session != null) && session.isRecording()) {
            try {    
                   session.stop();                                      
                   session.save();                                      
                   session = null;           
            }   
            catch (e instanceof Lang.Exception) {           
                System.println(e.getErrorMessage());
          }                        
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C.

Comment: Its monkey C. https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/monkey-c/

Comment: ...and Monkey C is not C.